# Losing precision when saving a DateTimeOffset setting in project settings

Tags: c#, serialization, application-settings, datetimeoffset

When I save a `DateTimeOffest` in my project settings, I'm losing some precision :
[image: Losing precision on DateTimeOffset serialization]

The first variable is the original value, before serialization.
The second is the value after Deserialization.

In fact my variable is serialized like this in the config file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
    <userSettings>
        <MyApp.Properties.Settings>
            [...]
            <setting name="LatestCheckTimestamp" serializeAs="String">
                <value>02/22/2013 14:39:06 +00:00</value>
            </setting>
            [...]
        </MyApp.Properties.Settings>
    </userSettings>
</configuration>
```

**Is there a way to specify some serialization parameters to increase precision ?**

I know I can use some workaround, for example by storing the Ticks and the offset value or something like that, but I d'like to know if there's not a better way.

**EDIT** :
More info : I'm using the standard Visual Studio project settings to store my value :

```
MyApp.Settings.Default.LatestCheckTimestamp = initialLatestCheckTimestamp;
MyApp.Settings.Default.Save();
```

`MyApp.Settings` is the class generated by Visual studio when you edit settings in the project properties page.

**EDIT 2 : Solution** :

Base on the answer of Matt Johnson, this is what I did :

1. Renamed the setting from `LatestCheckTimestamp` to `LatestCheckTimestampString` but **not in my code**
2. Added the following Wrapper in an independent file to complete the partial class `Settings` :

.

```
public DateTimeOffset LatestCheckTimestamp
{
    get { return DateTimeOffset.Parse(LatestCheckTimestampString); }
    set { LatestCheckTimestampString = value.ToString("o"); }
}
```

The new config file now looks like :

```
<configuration>
    <userSettings>
        <MyApp.Properties.Settings>
            [...]
            <setting name="LatestCheckTimestampString" serializeAs="String">
                <value>2013-02-22T16:54:04.3647473+00:00</value>
            </setting>
        </MyApp.Properties.Settings>
    </userSettings>
</configuration>
```

... and my code still is

```
MyApp.Settings.Default.LatestCheckTimestamp = initialLatestCheckTimestamp;
MyApp.Settings.Default.Save();
```

Comment: Are you planning on supporting multiple windows users? If so, does each have their own "last check time" or is shared among all of them? One of the problems with ApplicationSettingsBase (the class your Settings class is derived from) is that it won't allow writing to application scoped settings (though there are workarounds).

Comment: @jerry my setting is user scoped. No problem on that. Thanks for asking.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The most reliable way to serialize a `DateTimeOffset` is with the [RoundTrip pattern](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1.aspx#Roundtrip), which is specified with the `"o"` standard serialization string.

This uses the [ISO8601](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) standard, which is highly interoperable with other systems, languages, frameworks, etc.  Your value would look like this:  `2013-02-22T14:39:06.0000000+00:00`.

.Net will store fractional seconds to 7 decimals with this format.

If you can show some code of how you are storing and retrieving your app setting, I can show you where to specify the format string.  In most cases, its simply `.ToString("o")`.

Comment: Based on your answer, I made a wrapper for the value stored as string instead of DateTimeOffset. See my edit. Thanks !

Comment: That seems reasonable.  I dug in a bit to the MSDN docs, and it doesn't appear that you can specify the format string for the app settings.  It's crazy that they use the default format for this, Especially since it's culture sensitive.  The `"o"` format is much safer.